# Prometheus Metrics to find untagged and underutilized resources in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, prometheus, grafana, aws-billing

Can someone Suggest how we can find the untagged and underutilized resources based on CPU and Memory in Prometheus ?
Can we use CE api to get the details ?

Comment: what metrics do you have already in prometheus? are you using node exporter?

Comment: Yes , we are using node exporter to fetch all system related metrics